# GitHub fork a forked repository

Tags: github, repository

Does anyone know how to fork a forked repository on GitHub?

what I'm trying to achieve is to fork the updated `repository` from a `user` that `forked` the `original repository` and maintained it.

e.g.:

**Original repository and *abandoned repository***

- john/some-random-stuff

**Forked repository from another user who *maintained it***

- smith/some-random-stuff

Now, I want to fork the `smith/some-random-stuff` and *not* the `john/some-random-stuff`.

So now in my profile it'll show `forked from smith/some-random-stuff`

Edit:
when I click the fork on `smith/some-random-stuff` it still forking the original repo which is `john/some-random-stuff`

Comment: You just need to click on the `Fork` button on the forked repo `smith/some-random-stuff` on GitHub

Comment: i did, but it's forking the original repo

Comment: oh sorry. such a mistake. I don't know, but I tried it now and it forked the `smith/some-random-stuff` repo such weird things

Comment: I have forked a repository. now I want to make a new fork from a forked repository of that original repository, however, it is not possible! –

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just clicking the **Fork** button on the GitHub page of the forked repo would **create you a fork of the forked repo**. If you hover on the **Fork** button on the page of `smith/some-random-stuff` fork, it would show

> Fork your own copy of smith/some-random-stuff to your account

So you just need to click on the **Fork** button on the page of the fork `smith/some-random-stuff`

Comment: I have forked a repository. now I want to make a new fork from a forked repository of that original repository, however, it is not possible!